# Google Translate Using Diffrent Spellings of Words

Tags: google-translate

I have a site that is using Google Translate embeded on the site because it will have users of various languages using the site. On the site there are some different spelling for words. Some of these are meant to be fun and not real words. For instance on the site we have the word `Kreate` which equals `Create`.

Is there a way to tell Google that certain words equal other words and then translate them accordingly?

I have seen the Glossary feature of Google Translate that looks like it will allow me to add these words for a specific language. Is it possible to apply the word to all languages automatically?